# What theorem is the equation below based on?

Tags: calculus

I saw an equation in the proof of Helmholtz Theorem, which is:

$\oint \hat{n} \times \vec{v} d^2r=\int_V \nabla \times \vec{v}d^3r$

I am not sure what theorem does this equation base on. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With $\cdot$, i.e. inner product rather than with $\times$ (cross product) it is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem . In fact, looking through the Wikipedia page, it seems that what you have here is a corollary anyways!

Comment: This is just the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by considering an arbitrary (non-zero) constant vector $\vec{c}$ alongside our vector field $\vec{v}$.  We have
$$
\vec{\nabla} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{c}) = \vec{c} \cdot (\vec{\nabla}  \times \vec{v}) - \vec{v} \cdot (\vec{\nabla}  \times \vec{c}) = \vec{c} \cdot (\vec{\nabla}  \times \vec{v})
$$
since $\vec{c}$ is constant.  Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
\vec{c} \cdot \left[ \int_V \vec{\nabla}  \times \vec{v} \, d^3\vec{r} \right] &= \int_V \vec{c} \cdot \left( \vec{\nabla}  \times \vec{v} \right) \, d^3r \\
&= \int_V \vec{\nabla} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{c}) \, d^3r \\
&= \oint_{\partial V} (\vec{v} \times \vec{c}) \cdot \hat{n}\, d^2r & \text{(divergence theorem)}\\
&= \oint_{\partial V} \vec{c} \cdot (\hat{n} \times \vec{v}) \, d^2r & \text{(triple product)}\\
&= \vec{c} \cdot \left[ \oint_{\partial V} \hat{n} \times \vec{v} \, d^2r \right].
\end{align*}

Since this holds for any non-zero vector $\vec{c}$, it must be that the quantities in square brackets are equal to each other, and the identity is proven.  (If this isn't obvious, note that taking $\vec{c} = \hat{\imath}, \hat{\jmath}$ and $\hat{k}$ in turn proves the identity for the $x$-, $y$-, and $z$- components of the identity.)